# how to delete document from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

I need to delete one doc from firebase by clicking on it's icon. The problem is I dont't know how to tag the specific id of each doc in vuetify

this is my card (1 card for 1 project)

```
  <v-card flat v-for="project in projects" :key="project.title">
    <v-layout row wrap :class="`pa-3 project ${project.status}`">
      <v-flex xs12 md6>
        <div class="caption grey--text">Project title</div>
        <div>{{ project.title }}</div>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs6 sm4 md2>
        <div class="caption grey--text">Person</div>
        <div>{{ project.person }}</div>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs6 sm4 md2>
        <div class="caption grey--text">Due by</div>
        <div>{{ project.due }}</div>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2 sm4 md2>
      <v-btn flat color='red' slot='activator' class='right mx-0 my-0' @click='deleteProject()'>
      <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
     </v-btn>
        <div>
          <v-chip small :class="`${project.status} white--text caption mx-0`">{{ project.status}}</v-chip>
        </div>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
  </v-card>
```

And this method I try to write

```
deleteProject() {
  console.log('deleted');
  let idP = element.id; // obviously that i have problem with this line
  db.collection('projects').doc(idP).delete()
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but for now I have an error telling me that i am not specifying element i want to delete correctly, so i think the problem is idP variable

Answer (score 1):

I think you are fetching `projects` from `firebase` and you will always get an Id for firebase document you are fetching. You should store that `id` with rest of the values. After that when you are calling your `deleteProject` function you can pass your `Id` in that function like this.

```
<v-btn flat color='red' slot='activator' class='right mx-0 my-0' @click='deleteProject(project.Id)'>
```

And than receive the Id in your function like this

```
deleteProject(Id) {
  console.log('deleted');
  db.collection('projects').doc(Id).delete()
}
```

Hopefully, this will solve your problem.

Comment: yeah! thnks a lot u r the best !

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКасютич Happy to help :)